# How to respond with embeds

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Currently I am trying to work on my bot and update its responses. Right now I am trying to use the code below to make it respond with the random embeds I made. For some reason when doing using this code the bot either responds with "NaN" or "3"?

```
const embeds = [`${yellowinfocommandembed}`, `${whiteinfocommandembed}`, `${redinfocommandembed}`, `${purpleinfocommandembed}`, `${pinkinfocommandembed}`, `${orangeinfocommandembed}`,`${limeinfocommandembed}`,`${greeninfocommandembed}`,`${cyaninfocommandembed}`,`${browninfocommandembed}`,`${blueinfocommandembed}`,`${blackinfocommandembed}` ];
const embed = Math.floor(Math.random() * embeds.length);
    if(message.channel.type == "dm") {
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
        else {
            message.delete ();
            message.channel.send(embed);
        }
}
```

Comment: I honestly am unsure as working with the randomness is brand new to me but it is actually doing random math instead of randomizing the response?

Comment: Please don't tag javascript questions with java. They are two separate languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of:

```js
Math.floor(Math.random() * embeds.length);
```

Is to generate a pseudo-random integer between 0 and the length of the array (floored). This does not provide a random element from an array. You can use this number to *get* an element from an array using bracket syntax.

```js
const arr = ['Peach', 'Pear', 'Plum', 'Pomegranate'];
const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

console.log(`The random number: ${num}`);
console.log(`The corresponding array element: ${arr[num]}`);
```

---

Edit:

You'll have to understand template literals to realize why your bot is sending `[object Object]`. Template literals (`${variable}`) are mainly used for two purposes

- To merge together a string and variable, or multiple variables
- **To coerce a variable's data type to a string**

Here's an example of the second purpose.

```js
// normal usage: (`1 + 1 is ${1 + 1}`) => 1 + 1 is 2

console.log(typeof 10); // just the number 10
console.log(typeof `${10}`); // but if I put it in a teplate literal, it coerces itself to a string

// of course, this also applies for concatenation using the + operator

// normal usage: ('1 + 1 is ' + (1 + 1)) => 1 + 1 is 2
console.log(typeof 10); // just the number two
console.log(typeof ('' + 10)); // but if I merge it with an empty string, it coerces itself to a string
```

Why is this important? `orangeinfocommandembed`, for example, is an instance of the `MessageEmbed` class. So when that gets coerced to a string, it becomes `[object Object]`.

```js
const obj = { foo: 'bar' };
console.log(`${obj}`); // [object Object]
```

Sorry, that's a long explanation for a relatively easy fix. Just remove the template literals and only use the base variables.

```js
const embeds = [
 yellowinfocommandembed,
 whiteinfocommandembed,
 redinfocommandembed,
 purpleinfocommandembed,
 pinkinfocommandembed,
 orangeinfocommandembed,
 limeinfocommandembed,
 greeninfocommandembed,
 cyaninfocommandembed,
 browninfocommandembed,
 blueinfocommandembed,
 blackinfocommandembed,
];
```

Comment: Thank you for answering one of my questions again! Again helped me, but now my problem is it just says "[object Object]" I am assuming because the way I am calling it emebeds cant be done this way. Is it possible for it to send the embed instead of just saying "[object Object]"

`
      if(message.channel.type == "dm") {
            message.channel.send(`${embeds[embed]}`);
        }
            else {
                message.delete ();
                message.channel.send(`${embeds[embed]}`);
            }
    }``

Comment: I'll edit my question to show why this is happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const embeds = [yellowinfocommandembed, whiteinfocommandembed, redinfocommandembed, purpleinfocommandembed, pinkinfocommandembed, orangeinfocommandembed, limeinfocommandembed, greeninfocommandembed, cyaninfocommandembed, browninfocommandembed, blueinfocommandembed, blackinfocommandembed];
const embed = embeds[Math.floor(Math.random() * embeds.length)];

if(message.channel.type != "dm"){
    message.delete();
}

message.channel.send(embed);
```

2 problems:

1. In the "embeds" array you were saving the embeds as a string by using the `, not an embed.
2. In the "embed" you were only generating a random number, not getting the random element from the embeds array which you can see how to do in my provided code.

Comment: Thank you, so it is the way I am calling the embed in?

Comment: yes, to get an element from an array you call the array and specify the index (which is random in this case) of the element in the square brackets.